# Visual Studio QT Tools generate language files for all projects in solution

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-vs-addin

I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple QT projects in it (Visual Studio QT tools). I want to generate one .ts file per language for the entire solution, but the QT tools lupdate command only looks in the current project for texts.

I have tried adding $(SolutionDir) and $(SolutionDir)[Subproject] paths to the "Include Path" option in the Qt Project settings, in hope that it would search the entire Solution for translatable texts, but it did not effect the .ts files.